# Delete older component version from bit

Tags: reactjs, bit, bit.dev

I know, from github we can delete older version.
Is there option to delete older version of components created using bit.dev?
if yes, can you guide me through it? How older version can be deleted?

Comment: bit does not support deleting a specific version. if you just create a new version, all your consumers will be able to update to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In Bit, when you want to remove a component, you want to `deprecate` it. Deleting a component is dangerous: it can lead to possible damage to dependent components and projects. You will need to refactor its dependents to guarantee its functioning.

Instead, you will want to deprecate them:

```
bit deprecate <component-name>
```

Now, instead of just deprecating them, you can also provide a `new-id` if you intend to replace them with another component:

```
bit deprecate <component-name> --new-id <new-component-id>
```

Once deprecated the component, don't forget to `snap` / `tag` and `export`.

[Docs](https://bit.dev/docs/components/removing-components)